# how to handle the return values from reducer, inside a functional component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

This may be a basic question, but I'm new to React Native and stuck here.

My code pasted below. reducer and functional component. I want to capture the response returned from reducer.

**reducer.js**

```js
export const ActivationCenterReducer = (
  state = INIT_KIT_STATE,
  { type, payload = {} }
) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'KIT_ACTIVATION_SUCCESS_DATA': {
      const { message, response_code, apiLoading, apiError } = payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        apiLoading: apiLoading,
        apiError: apiError,
        message: message,
        response_code: response_code
      };
    }
    // ...
  }
  // ...
};
```

**Functional Component class:**

```js
const kitActivationCenter = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const response_code = useSelector(
    store => store.kitActivationCenter.response_code
  );

  const handleKitActivation = () => {
    /*This will call the validation() inside action.js and that follows the reducer.js file. where reducer.js file returning the values on success response. but I am not able to access that response_code returned from reducer.
  
  How to save the response_code from the below dispatch function.*/

    dispatch(Validation(locator, pin));

    if (response_code === 200) {
      // should navigate to the next screen
    }
  };
};
```

My question is how to capture the returned response_code from reducer.

I'm able to navigate to the next screen on clicking the submit button couple of times.I notice that first time when the dispatch function is called, the state of the response_code is not updating , hence the response_code != 200.

I want a way to capture the response and assign to variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking at the old value of `response_code` in your `handleKitActivation`.

```js
const kitActivationCenter = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const response_code = useSelector(
    store => store.kitActivationCenter.response_code
  );

  const handleKitActivation = () => {
    dispatch(Validation(locator, pin));

    // HERE the response_code does not have result value
    //   of your calling dispatch(Validation(locator, pin)) above yet
    if (response_code === 200) {
      // should navigate to the next screen
    }
  };
};
```

I suggest to move your response_code hanfling to the `useEffect`:

```js
const kitActivationCenter = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const response_code = useSelector(
    store => store.kitActivationCenter.response_code
  );

  // this effect will run whenever your response_code changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (response_code === 200) {
      // should navigate to the next screen
    }
  }, [response_code]);

  const handleKitActivation = () => {
    dispatch(Validation(locator, pin));
  };
};
```